# Is is possible to show the beamer output full screen on monitor 2 like powerpoint?

Tags: beamer, pdf

I was wondering whether it is possible to full screen the pdf i.e beamer output in monitor 2 showing the contents in monitor 1 as well. I am using monitor extend properties in windows. Powerpoint has that feature. I don't know whether that feature is also available in pdf or not. I am using adobe acrobat X. I have a presentation tomorrow morning. Please help asap.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right place to ask this question; either that, or I'm not really sure what exactly you're asking.  I've used PPT before, but tend to leave the presentation itself to other group members where possible.  Can you provide a screenshot of sorts as to what you're looking for?

Comment: Actually I tried my computer on the presentation room. It seems my computer only supports extended mode. Under these situations how can I display the pdf on both my monitor and the external monitor ? IN the powerpoint, if you go to slide show, then you have a option to `show on` and then choose the appropriate monitor. I don't know whether pdf has that feature

Comment: Windows has a feature to show the same contents in 2 monitors. Read [it](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Set-up-multiple-monitors) if you are using Windows.

Comment: @Jdbaba If your computer supports extended monitor it MUST support duplicates, both most likely you have to change the resolutions (there are some limitations regarding the supported resolutions when using two monitors).  For this reason, I recommend you match the resolutions, preferably using a low one just to be sure

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about specific settings regarding Windows dual-monitor setups.

Comment: PDF viewer (at least Acrobat, and I'm assuming the general viewer too), under the View tab, has a "full screen mode" which is what I think you want. Alt-V F is the shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to have the same display for PDF as for a normal power point presentation. But if you want to display the PDF on both screens why don't you mirror your displays? (You should be able to do that in the Monitor/Display settings)

"Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display\Screen Resolution"

there should be a menu with "Multiple Displays" and and option do duplicate the display.

Comment: Actually I tried that at the first point but the projecter doesn't somehow recognize my computer when using the option "duplicate the display". It detects on "only the projector" option and "extend desktop". I can show presentation on the projector this way but cannot show on my computer.

Comment: @Jdbaba: what is the maker of your video adapter? NVidia?

Comment: @ Yes, for my laptop it is NVidia.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach?

1. Extend the desktop
2. Open the PDF file
3. At least Adobe Reader has the command:

   ```
   Window > New Window
   ```
4. Move the second window to the extended desktop